# Как восстановить php.ini на Ubuntu 14?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Случайно стер php.ini в /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini Можно его как-то восстановить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно скопировать отсюда `/usr/share/php5/php.ini-production`

```
sudo cp /usr/share/php5/php.ini-production /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то что надо!